# Proving a metric space is separable

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space which satisfies the following condition:$$$$If $\{ F_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in \Gamma}$ is a family of closed sets such that $\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb N} F_{\alpha_i} \neq \emptyset$ for every enumerable subset of the family then $\bigcap_{\alpha \in \Gamma} F_\alpha \neq \emptyset$$$$$Prove that X is separable.
$$$$I have a general doubt: would the proof of this be equivalent to prove that if this condition doesn't hold for some family, then X is not separable? Because I could prove this, but I am not so sure the equivalence is true (I have problems with logic, as you can see).

Suppose $X$ is not separable. Then, there exists an open cover $\{ C_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \Gamma}$, such that for every enumerable subset $\{ C_{\alpha_i}\}_{i \in \mathbb N}$ $X\neq\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb N} C_{\alpha_i}$. So, for every enumerable subset, there exists $x \in X$ such that $x \not\in \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb N} C_{\alpha_i}$. But then $x \in (\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb N} C_{\alpha_i})^c$=$\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb N} X \setminus C_{\alpha_i}$. So, we have a family of closed sets $\{ X \setminus C_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \Gamma}$  which satisfies $\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb N} X \setminus C_{\alpha_i}\neq \emptyset$ for every enumerable subset. But then $\bigcap_{\alpha \in \Gamma} X \setminus C_\alpha= (\bigcup_{\alpha \in \Gamma} X \setminus C_{\alpha})^c=\emptyset$

Is my corrected proof ok?

I'll leave the other implication as well (If X is a separable metric space, then the condition holds)

Suppose there exists a family of closed sets such that  $\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb N} F_{\alpha_i} \neq \emptyset$ for every enumerable subset of the family and that $\bigcap_{\alpha \in \Gamma} F_\alpha=\emptyset$. Then X is not separable. Proof: Suppose X is separable. $X=(\bigcap_{\alpha \in \Gamma} F_\alpha)^c$=$\bigcup_{\alpha \in \Gamma} X \setminus F_\alpha$. Then $\bigcup_{\alpha \in \Gamma} X \setminus F_\alpha$ is an open cover of X. By hypothesis, there is an enumerable open subcover $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb N} X \setminus F_{\alpha_i}$ such that $X=\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb N} X \setminus F_{\alpha_i}$. We take complement again and obtain $\emptyset=X^c=(\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb N} X \setminus F_{\alpha_i})^c=\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb N} F_{\alpha_i}$. But this is absurd by our hypothesis. The absurd comes from the assumption that X was separable, then X is not separable.

Comment: "By hypothesis, there is an enumerable open subcover" That means you've already proved that a separable metric space is Lindelöf?

Comment: Yes, I've already proved that. I mean, we've proved in our class that a metric space is separable if and only if for every open cover there is an enumerable open subcover of the space. We can use that in this exercise.

Comment: Okay, so now you are to prove the converse, a Lindelöf metric space is separable. There are plenty of ways to prove that, I think, what comes to my mind first is to use a countable family of open covers, extracting a countable subcover from each, and ...

Comment: But in this exercise I am assumming that if a metric space is separable then every open cover has an open subcover, because we've already proved it in my class.

Comment: You’re trying to prove the converse. The implication that **is** equivalent to the desired result is that if $X$ is not separable, then the condition does not hold for some family of closed sets.

Comment: You have already proved $(S) \Rightarrow (L)$. Now your task is to prove $(L) \Rightarrow (S)$, where $(S)$ is "the metric space is separable" and $(L)$ is "the metric space is Lindelöf" (and Lindelöf means every open cover has a countable subcover). The given condition is just another phrasing of $(L)$. [Important note: The equivalence between separability and Lindelöfness is for **metric** spaces, in general, the two are not equivalent.]

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I'll correct my original proof.